# How to convert javascript VAR URL into another formats?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image gallery viewer and currently it is showing the data from online sources,

```
var url = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + photo.server + '/' + photo.id + '_' + photo.secret,
```

i want to get the images from

```
http://localhost/profiler/img/
```

Here I have many pictures and want to show them in the gallery viewer.

Comment: whats stopping you from creating another variable; also what do you mean by "convert"?

Comment: You'r question is not clear. What do you need to do? Do you have to put `var url = ...` into `php` or do you want to get local images ?